# Can't go to main activity from login activty(with background task)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm making an app with a login feature, but I have a problem where when I put right account info, I can't go to main activity, the login activity seems to relaunch:

My backgroundTask from login activty:

```
  @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
try {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray jsonArray =  jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
    JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
    String code = jo.getString("code");
    String message = jo.getString("message");
    if (code.equals("reg_true")){
        showDialog("Register succes", message, code);
    }
    else if (code.equals("reg_false")){
        showDialog("Register fail", message, code);
    }
    else if (code.equals("login_true")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        activity.startActivity(intent);

        //activity.finish(); // i tried with finish but i loose the itent extra i need for sharedpreference
    }
```

Login class:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText Mail,Password;
Button Login;
TextView toRegister;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lMail);
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lPassword);
    Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
    toRegister = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.toRegister);

    toRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
        }
    });

    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if ( Mail.getText().toString().equals("") || Password.getText().toString().equals("") ){
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Attention");
                builder.setMessage("Rempliser tout les champs");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            else{
                BackgroundTask bt = new BackgroundTask(LoginActivity.this);
                bt.execute("login" ,Mail.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString() );
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Disable going back to the MainActivity
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

}

If anything is missing, you can find my mainactivty and manifest on gist:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/efc3400df01a0b972a71

edit: log here:

```
03-28 20:40:01.539 954-4500/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.serk.comparateurL3F1/.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10169 on display 0
03-28 20:40:01.550 954-4500/? D/ActivityManager: finishRunningVoiceLocked()  >>>>
03-28 20:40:01.562 954-4007/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b2323bc attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@2dc1afc
03-28 20:40:01.600 24100-24100/? I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
03-28 20:40:01.659 954-4500/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.serk.comparateurL3F1/.LoginActivity} from uid 10169 on display 0
03-28 20:40:01.665 954-4500/? D/ActivityManager: finishRunningVoiceLocked()  >>>>
03-28 20:40:01.704 954-3708/? D/WindowManager: relayoutVisibleWindow: Window{452fac1 u0 com.serk.comparateurL3F1/com.serk.comparateurL3F1.MainActivity EXITING} mAnimatingExit=true, mRemoveOnExit=false, mDestroying=false
03-28 20:40:01.716 954-972/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Wait...) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:1738 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:816 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:1906 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:357 
03-28 20:40:01.742 24100-24100/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Points are too far apart 4.000001
03-28 20:40:01.882 24100-24100/? I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
03-28 20:40:01.884 24100-24100/? I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
03-28 20:40:02.065 954-972/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.serk.comparateurL3F1/.LoginActivity: +379ms (total +499ms)
03-28 20:40:02.097 3156-3156/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()
03-28 20:40:02.098 3156-3156/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onStartInput()
03-28 20:40:02.109 3156-3156/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
03-28 20:40:02.114 954-4003/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.serk.comparateurL3F1/com.serk.comparateurL3F1.MainActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:1738 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:816 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:1906 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.tryStartExitingAnimation:2830 
03-28 20:40:02.152 3918-13832/? D/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDataEnabled: subId=1 phoneId=0
03-28 20:40:02.153 3918-13832/? D/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getDataEnabled: subId=1 retVal=true
03-28 20:40:02.153 3218-3617/? D/TelephonyManager: getDataEnabled: retVal=true
03-28 20:40:02.167 3156-3156/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: resetDictionaries() : no-op
03-28 20:40:02.168 3156-3156/? I/StatsUtilsManager: onLoadSettings()
03-28 20:40:02.436 954-4005/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.serk.comparateurL3F1/com.serk.comparateurL3F1.LoginActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:1738 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:816 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:1906 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.tryStartExitingAnimation:2830
```

Comment: post your json response, logcat ,login and mainactivity java class

Comment: @ArpitPatel i added the log  
the json response is {"server_response":[{"code":"login_true","message":"test"}]} (from http://comparateur.16mb.com/logintest.html )  
you can find and all here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/efc3400df01a0b972a71

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what you are doing at the end on `MainActivity.onCreate(...)`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You are relaunching the `LoginActivity` yourself. If you do not want to do that then remove the above lines so `MainActvivity` continues to load properly.

Comment: Unfortunaly, this was not the solution, i added log when trying to login and to mainactivity

Comment: Well that was for sure part of your problem at least. Did you make sure `userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser() != null` after logging in in the `MainActivity.authenticate()` method? Might want to add another log statement to verify that or better yet set a few break points and debug `MainActivity` if you know how.

Comment: I think that was it, i guess that will teach me to try to implement 2 thing in same time, my sharedpreference is no setup yet so the check was null...
Thank you, i was going mad and checking in the wrong place
Your fist answer is still valid then? Because now i get to mainactivity directly instead of login activity

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I got the reason but could you check if you need this..
In line 82 and 83 in your main activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);        
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Unfortunaly, this was not the solution, i added log when trying to login and to mainactivity